# What do we remember in paradise from life?

Tags: death, life, jannah

In paradise, do we maintain what we had learned during our life on earth, I mean sciences, human inventions and so on?

Comment: I think yes because I have heard the there would be one place in Heaven where everyone would meet each other and discuss what they used to do in world.

Comment: I guess the answer would be pretty much everything from our earthly life. For instance, a man will ask Allah to allow him to do agriculture, which Allah will let him. In Jannah, there is no need for labour, so it naturally follows that the man will "remember" this from his earthly existence. Similarly, a man may want to rear camels in Jannah since he was extremely fond of them in his earthly life. So, if you are a computer programmer, you may even get the latest "tera-Hz" processor with infinite memory and storage capacity to write programs, if that was what you were fond of doing on earth. ;)

Comment: @Najeeb, you say "In Jannah, there is no need for labour", if there's no need to do anything in Janneh, wouldn't it be boring? What do we do in paradise (from what we know in islam)?

Comment: @user2651062, the topic of Jannah and its delights deserves a separate question. However, to sum it up: a man never gets bored of a woman, does he? He may get bored of driving around in flashy cars, living in the best penthouses, but a man will *never* get bored of women. Even when he is an octogenarian, his most ardent desire will be to have young women, though he may have had plenty of them in his youth. (I am not talking of the legitimacy of the matter, so please don't misunderstand what I am saying.) And that's one of the best blessings of Paradise: women, women, and more women. :)

Comment: And that's just one blessing. Jannah keeps getting better with time, just the way Jahannam keeps getting more and more painful. In Jannah, literally, your senses will keep evolving, and each fruit that you taste will taste different from the last one you ate, and it will be tastier. Allah will enhance your senses so that you taste those tastes that you have never tasted, you will see those sights and colors that you have never seen in your earthly existence, and you will hear music and notes that you have never heard. In short, the limitations of your five senses will be lifted there.

Comment: I would recommend that you google for some Shaykh's talk on Jannah and Jahannam. Insha Allah, their words will be more accurate and better in explanation than what I have just described.

Answer (score 1):

We will be able to relate to experiences of this world in the next, as mentioned it [this](http://quran.com/2/25) verse

> Whenever they are provided with a provision of fruit therefrom, they will say, "This is what we were provided with before." And it is given to them in likeness

To what extent we would remember this life, we have to wait and see. May Allah enter us all in His Heaven.